# SQL custom logic in constraints

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to create such custom constrain logic **no duplicate combination in one period of time**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CheckPriceListDuplicates](
@priceListId uniqueidentifier,
@supplierId uniqueidentifier,
@transportModeId uniqueidentifier,
@currencyId uniqueidentifier,
@departmentTypeId uniqueidentifier,
@consolidationModeId uniqueidentifier,
@importerId uniqueidentifier,
@exporterId uniqueidentifier,
@validFrom datetimeoffset(7),
@validTo datetimeoffset(7))
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @result int

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[PriceListEntries] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Id] <> @priceListId) AND 
        ((([Extent1].[SupplierAddressBook_Id] IS NULL) AND (@supplierId IS NULL)) OR ([Extent1].[SupplierAddressBook_Id] = @supplierId)) AND 
        ([Extent1].[TransportMode_Id] = @transportModeId) AND 
        ([Extent1].[Currency_Id] = @currencyId) AND 
        ([Extent1].[DepartmentType_Id] = @departmentTypeId) AND 
        ((([Extent1].[ConsolidationMode_Id] IS NULL) AND (@consolidationModeId IS NULL)) OR ([Extent1].[ConsolidationMode_Id] = @consolidationModeId)) AND 
        ((([Extent1].[Importer_Id] IS NULL) AND (@importerId IS NULL)) OR ([Extent1].[Importer_Id] = @importerId)) AND 
        ((([Extent1].[Exporter_Id] IS NULL) AND (@exporterId IS NULL)) OR ([Extent1].[Exporter_Id] = @exporterId)) AND 
        ((@validFrom >= [Extent1].[ValidFrom]) OR (@validTo <= [Extent1].[ValidTo]))
    )
BEGIN
    SET @result = 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @result = 1
END
RETURN @result
END

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PriceListEntries]
ADD CONSTRAINT UniquCombinations CHECK ([dbo].[CheckPriceListDuplicates](
Id,
SupplierAddressBook_Id,
TransportMode_Id,
Currency_Id,
DepartmentType_Id,
ConsolidationMode_Id,
Importer_Id,
Exporter_Id,
ValidFrom,
ValidTo) = 1)
```

any idea how to do with out function?

Comment: You can do that in the trigger. But what is wrong to use that function?

Comment: my teamlead doesnt approve this, he doesnt want any logic in DB, he accepts only constraints, but function already will be logic in other place.

Comment: You can not create constraint to check existing records. Even if you would find the way how to do that it seems to me that there still would be the logic in DB on constraint level. Why don't you want to check the record before you insert it in the CODE with the same logic you do in the function?

Comment: maybe somewhere, somehow will be added and validation will not be set, so thats why on constrains level. K I got your point, I will speak with him

Comment: If you are willing to standardize your time periods, you can do it with a UNIQUE constraint.   For example, replace the ValidFrom and ValidTo column with a ValidPeriod column that had values like "May 2015".  You could even use a daily ValidPeriod column for more granularity, but you'll have a lot more rows, probably.

Comment: Is your intent to check for _any_ overlapping valid period, not just a period contained within a existing period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a generally accepted concept that business rules should not be enforced in the DB. This is also generally difficult to strictly enforce as there is a large amount of overlap between business rules and data integrity rules. A data integrity constraint may limit a field to an integer value between 5 and 20, but that is because some business rule somewhere stipulates those are the only valid values.

So the difference between a business rule and a constraint is usually *de facto* defined as: a business rule is something that can't be easily enforced with the built-in checks available in the database and a constraint can be.

But I would further narrow the definition to state that a business rule is liable to change and a constraint is more static. For example, the rule "a patron may have no more than 5 library items checked out at any one time" could well be easily enforced using database constraints. But the limit of 5 is arbitrary and could change at a moments notice. Therefore it should be defined as a business rule that should not be enforced at the database level.

If a structural or modeling change or enhancement/addition of a database feature makes a "business rule" easily enforceable in the database where it wasn't before, you still have to consider if the rule is rigidly defined such that it is not expected to change. The database should be the bedrock, the foundation of your data edifice. You don't want it shifting around a lot.

Comment: I will add UNIQUE CONSTRAINT for columns, and entire range data validation with unique combination on code level. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

One way to query multiple columns in a table and see if they are all (together) unique is to Concatenate the tested data together as a string.

```
Select CONCAT ( Col1, Col2, Col3) AS ConcateString 
from [TABLE_NAME] 
WHERE ConcateString = 'All_of_your_data_in_one_string';
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

If the result yields more than one result, it combination of the data is not unique.

Comment: So "This is" + " a duplicate" + ", eh?" = "This " + "is a duplicate, " + "eh?"? It may be acceptable for fixed-width columns, but might present some surprises with other data.